# ¿Cómo arreglar mi terminal de Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Intentando arreglar un problema con python metí un comando a mi terminal de Ubuntu que  hizo que ya no pudiera abrir más la terminal. No recuerdo que comando era pero tenía que ver con la dirección de python. Ahora cuando intento abrir la terminal con ctrl + alt + t no pasa nada y tampoco si me voy al ícono de la terminal. Cuando intento el segundo método me sale el siguiente error:

Failed to launch "Terminal" 
Failed to execute child process "gnome-terminal" (too many levels of symbolic links)

Buscando en mi historial de web creo haber encontrado los comandos que generaron el problema.

sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4

Pero al segundo comando le cambié el 3.4 a 3.6 o 3.7. No me acuerdo exactamente porque tengo instaladas ambas versiones de python.

Comment: No sé si es relacionado, pero visita este [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083411/how-to-solve-the-error-failed-to-launch-terminal-after-upgrading-python) en inglés que le ocurren lo mismo, pero con la instalación/desinstalación/actualización de Python. Si no das más información, es difícil llegar a la solución del problema.

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no pasa nada. Creo que fueron estos dos comandos los que causaron el problema: sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6

Comment: ¿Puedes mirar las versiones de Python que tienes instaladas?

Comment: ¿Puedes entrar a la línea de comando con Alt+F2? ¿Has probado  CTRL+ALT+F3 o F4 para abrir una consola?

Comment: •¿No habrás echo rm /usr/bin? La consola se encuentra en esa misma carpeta, creo recordar

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a 'grosso modo' sería crear un usb de arranque de ubuntu, arrancar desde él, en lugar de instalar le das a probar, montas la unidad de tu disco duro donde esta instalado el Ubuntu y copias los ficheros que hayas eliminado.